# update .style attributes with setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to move the position of a div element at set intervals however the setInterval method executes once and then stops. setInterval() doesn't update .style.transform repeatedly every 200 milliseconds as intended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Snake game</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  #snakehead {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="snakehead"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript: Ideally I'd also like to be able to move the snakehead in any direction with vx and vy. Anyway to put those values into .style.transform = translateX()?

```
function snakepos() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var vx = 1;
    var vy = 0;
    return {
        move: function() {
                x += vx;
                y += vy;
                var snakehead = document.querySelector("#snakehead");
                snakedhead.style.left = "5px";
        }
    };
}

window.onload = function() {
    console.log("hi");
    var container = document.querySelector(".container");
    var snake = snakepos();

    setInterval(function() {
        snake.move();
    }, 200);
}
```

I know this can be done much easier in jQuery with .css but I'd to how this can be done in vanilla javascript. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a problem in your function. `snakehead.style.left = snakedhead.style.left == "5px";` is actually setting the value of `left`  to the result of `snakedhead.style.left == "5px"` (which is true/false, and not a value). What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @Dekel ops sorry, that was me just experimenting, I originally just had snakehead.style.left = "5px", it didn't work then either.

Comment: So if every time the value is set to `5px` - nothing will change. The first time  - the value will be 5px. and the second time it will be (again) 5px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
snakehead.style.left = (snakedhead.style.left + "5px");
```

or

```
snakehead.style.left = (snakedhead.style.left - "5px");
```

Comment: Or `snakedhead.style.left = vx + 'px';` since that seems to be where the change in x displacement is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something in a style a bit more familiar to me:

```
function snakepos() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.vx = 1;
  this.vy = 1;
  this.snakehead = document.querySelector("#snakehead");
  var me = this;
  this.move = function() {
    me.x += me.vx;
    me.y += me.vy;
    me.snakehead.style.top = me.y + "px";
    me.snakehead.style.left = me.x + "px";
  };

  return this;
}

  console.log("hi");
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  var snake = new snakepos();

  setInterval(function() {
    snake.move();
  }, 200);
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/td8opb0b/1/

Comment: Thank you, I went with something very similar to yours!